# Cannot push a folder to remote Repository because it's "up to date"

Tags: git, github

I have a React.js app in my Github Repo. Somehow the node_modules directory is missing. Luckily I still have it in my local repo (is that the correct way to name it?).

However, if I want to push it to the remote repo, it says "Everything up-to-date".

Here is what I tried:

```
$ git add node_modules/
$ git commit -m "added missing node modules"
On branch master
nothing to commit, working tree clean
$ git push origin master
Everything up-to-date
```

[image: Github remote Repo without node_modules]

Comment: Sounds like `node_modules` is in your `.gitignore` (as it should be, according to some). That means you can't commit it (read the response after the commit command, it even told you that there was nothing to commit).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are new to JS and NodeJS, one thing to understand is you don't need `node_modules` in your remote repo. The reason being they are dependencies which are used only during execution or build.

If you still insist that you want to have your node_modules, you can remove the `node_module/` line from `.gitignore` file and it should be able to push both of them together. But I would highly recommend not to do that.

Comment: Within the whole project I do also have a backend with Express.js. There also is a node_modules directory. This got committed. Is it because create-react-app added it to it's own directory?

Comment: yes. it could be that those node_modules are not added to .gitignore and so they are added. As a rule of thumb, we should not put any node_modules into remote repo.